# difference for char* and char [] in C structure

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

When I want to store dynamic array of data in a C structure, there are two ways to write it:

```
typedef struct {
   int row;
   int col;
   char* data;
} item1;
```

Or

```
typedef struct {
   int row;
   int col;
   char data[];
} item2;
```

Both of them will work. But they got some differences on my 64bit Mac OSX, with gcc Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38):

```
      sizeof(item1) is 16
      sizeof(item2) is 8
```

Why is the difference? And, what else are different for the two implementations?

The full testing code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int row;
  int col;
  char* data;
} item1;


typedef struct {
  int row;
  int col;
  char data[];
} item2;


int main() {
  printf("%d %d\n", sizeof(item1), sizeof(item2));
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
16 8
```

Comment: Possible duplicate:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c

Comment: There is no `item1` or `item2` provided. The `typedef`s aren't complete either, both of which seem connected.

Comment: `typedef`s are still incomplete, and a call like `sizeof(item1)` won't work under these circumstances.

Comment: Please copy-and-paste your exact code.

Comment: I deleted my answer. @ThoAppelsin is right. `sizeof` will not work here. You have posted some other code.

Comment: @haccks I've added `sizeof(struct ...)`. That's all that's needed to make it work. I guess would be nice if the OP can confirm. But that does create the same results, (well IDE one reports 12 and 8: http://ideone.com/2trkZD)

Comment: I have updated the question to give the full code. @haccks

Comment: @weston; Yes. Added that to answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Size of pointer is [machine specific](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13109666/2455888) (whether it is 32-bit or 64-bit). The result would be `12` and `8` bytes respectively on 32 bit machine. For 64-bit machine, answer would be `16` and `8` bytes.
See the explanation

```
typedef struct {
   int row;         // 4 bytes
   int col;         // 4 bytes
   char* data;      // 4/8 bytes on 32/64-bit machine
}item1 ;
```

Total size = 12/16 bytes on 32/64 bit machine.

```
typedef struct {
   int row;         // 4 bytes
   int col;         // 4 bytes
   char data[];     // 0 bytes --> Flexible array 
}item2 ;
```

Total size = 8 bytes.

**Why size of flexible array is `0`?**

#### C11: 6.7.2.1 (p18)

> [...] In particular, **the size of the structure is as if the flexible array member were omitted** [...]

Comment: 4+4+4=12. Are you missing something? xD

Comment: @JamesHunt; Yes. Iwas missing :)

Comment: I think 16 bytes for 64 bit is a good rule of thumb, but worth noting that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2505999/360211) says it's controllable with pragmas and compiler settings, so may not always be the case.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct item2 {
   int row;
   int col;
   char data[];
}
```

in this struct `item2` we have 2 ints, so the size will be `2*sizeof(int)` in most of the systems, and also we have an array `char data[]` with undefined size so it counts as zero in this case, I think if there is padding in the struct then the amount of elements that the array will store will be related with the pading, but I am not sure.

total= 8 bytes.

```
typedef struct item1 {
   int row;    
   int col;
   char* data;
}
```

In this struct we have 2 ints that means 8 bytes ocupped by ints, and a pointer in a 64 bit system that means another 8 bytes.

total= 16 bytes.

There are a few things you need to know, there is no padding in this case an neither in
`item2`. and the diferrence between `char* data;` and `char data[];` is that the last one is an array that will be allocated in the stack, and the first one is a pointer allocated in the stack that will be commonly used with dynamic memory from the heap.